# Allow only one connection to SQLITE .db file using Java JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using Java 8 and [Xerial SQLITE JDBC Driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc).

I have an application which has multiple users, each user has each own database(`dbFile.db`), but any user can also connect to the databases of other users when they are not connected.

The problem is that I want only one user to be able to connect to the `dbFile.db` every time, and if he/she doesn't disconnect from it (close database connection), then no other user should be able to open a connection with that database file.

The code is simple, I am just opening a connection using JDBC and Java 8.

```
 try {
        //!I want here to check if another user is connected to the database!
       if(otherUserConnected)
            return;

        // Open connection
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/../../users/d/dbFile.db");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Main.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "", ex);
    }
```

Comment: SQLite isn't a real RDBMS; it's just a file.  You're going to have to manage that kind of requirement yourself.

Comment: I would create a properties DB. I would have a column named property. In the column I would add connectionEstablished. I would then create a column named state. I would set the that value to false. I would check this property value before allow someone to connect to the other db. Once some on connects to the other db, would set to value to true. When they disconnect, I would set it back to false.

Comment: @Makoto Does MySql provides such a mechanism?  I can change.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Hello Sedrick .  Here comes always this problem.  What if the application is terminated from Task Bar or some error. The bad will be locked forever. Cause the lock will remain.  I need ideas to solve it.

Comment: Good point! You have to use the block that always run on close.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode) to prevent any other connection to the database.

Comment: Can I have Java code for it please ☺️? What would happen if the user terminates the application from Task Bar? The 'PRAGMA'  will be forever the same?

Comment: A pragma is an SQL command; just execute it. SQLite uses the OS locking functions, so Windows would automatically remove the lock.

Comment: Why your answer gets downvoted ? Maybe because you have provided only the link. If you add some lines of code i can accept it :)